# How to get the ASCII value of a character in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ascii

How to get the ASCII value of a character in Haskell? I've tried to use the `ord` function in GHCi, based on what I read [here](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-Char.html#6) bug the the error message:

> Not in scope: `ord'

For example:

```
GHCi, version 6.12.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package ffi-1.0 ... linking ... done.
Prelude> ord 'a'

<interactive>:1:0: Not in scope: `ord'
Prelude>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `:module +Data.Char` (in GHCi) or `import Data.Char` (in your source file).

Comment: @Travis Brown: You can do `import Data.Char` in ghci too

Comment: @newacct: Cool—I didn't know that. `qualified` &c. don't work, though, apparently.

Comment: @TravisBrown `qualified` works!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As [Travis Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334519/travis-brown) indicated in a comment, you have to import the [`ord`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Char.html#v:ord) function from the module [`Data.Char`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Char.html):

```
import Data.Char (ord)

main = print (ord 'a')
```

Only the [`Prelude`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html) module is loaded by default, all other modules have to be imported explicitly.

Comment: Is this just a ghci thing? Or do i have to import these kind of modules when i'm making .hs files too?

Comment: @Chris: Only stuff defined in `Prelude` is imported by default, for other modules you have to specify additional imports.

Answer (score 19):

You can also use `fromEnum`. (defined in `Enum` class, from Prelude.)

```
Prelude> :i Char
data Char = GHC.Types.C# GHC.Prim.Char#     -- Defined in `GHC.Types'
instance Enum Char -- Defined in `GHC.Enum'
instance Eq Char -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
...
```

So you can use `fromEnum` and `toEnum`, which uses the ASCII code as the Int value.

```
Prelude> fromEnum 'A'
65
Prelude> fromEnum 'a'
97
Prelude> toEnum 9 :: Char
'\t'
Prelude> toEnum 100 :: Char
'd'
```

Comment: Is there any reason *not* to use this?

Comment: I prefer fromEnum / toEnum to the 'ord' function. They are both part of the Prelude, too.